# JQuery delay to Bootstrap Modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find an easy way to auto close my modals after openning and while i can do intervals w/c will require a few lines of code, i thought that the delay() of jquery would've been easier..

so in the trigger function for when the modal is displayed I have this:

```
$("#modalUserConfirm").delay(3000).modal('hide');
```

but this is not working.. the modal closes as soon as it opens..

Perhaps it's just not compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#modalUserConfirm")
    .delay(3000)
    .queue(function(){ $(this).modal('hide').dequeue(); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TUy9p/

Comment: hey Derek, thanks .. it works but for some reason it just works "once". .. the succeeding modal activation stays open .. function doesn't seem to fire anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you can share more code or an example that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I would soon as i can get back to my PC>. but for now, it's really just simple Modal.. i have a function listening for when the modal is show, it fires that code you wrote to auto hide it after 3 seconds.. so basically everytime the modal is shown this code/function is recreated ...

Comment: @BrownChiLD - I forgot to add `.dequeue();` into the function. It should work now. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TUy9p/).